# Classifying the linearity of the given PDE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I just wanted to make sure my reasoning behind the classification of the following PDE's is correct (note $u=u(x,t))$:

a) $$u_t -u_{xx}=0$$
-This is second order as the highest order term has order 2
-Linear as it consists of a linear combination of $u$ and its partial derivatives

b)$$(u_{xt})^2 + u_xu_{ttt}=xt^2$$
 -3rd order as the highest order term has order 3
 - Non -linear  because of the term $u_xu_{ttt}$ and $(u_{xt})^2$
 - Not quasi-liner as the highest order partial derivative $u_xu_{ttt}$ is multiplied by a derivative of u. Hence it is not semi linear.

c)$$uu_{x}+x^2tu_{tt}=1$$
 -This is second order as the highest order term has order 2
 - Non -linear  because of the term $uu_{x}$
 - Quasi-liner as the highest order partial derivative $u_{tt}$ is linear but is multiplied by a derivative of u.
 - Semi linear  as the highest  order derivative is not multiplied by u or any of its derivatives

d)$$u_{xx} + uu_{xxtt}=0$$
 -4th order  as the highest order term has order 4
 - Non -linear  because of the term $uu_{xxtt}$
- Quasi-liner as the highest order partial derivative $uu_{xxtt}$ is linear but is multiplied by u.
 - not Semi linear  as the highest  order partial derivative is multiplied by u

Comment: a), c) and d) are correct. The equation b) is quasilinear, but not semilinear.

Comment: how can b) quasi-linear if its highest order term is multiplied by a derivative of u?

Comment: A partial differential equation is said to be quasilinear if it is linear with respect to all the highest order derivatives of the unknown function.
In b)  the term, $u_xu_{ttt}$, is linear in the highest order derivative $u_{ttt}$.

Comment: im pretty new to this, i dont fully grasp the concept? in my course we've been told that the coefficients of the highest order derivates cannot be derivatives of u

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425413/quasilinear-pde-definition).

Comment: so am I correct in assuming that the PDE:
$u_tu_{ttt}+u_{tt}=0$ is an example of a quasi-linear PDE as w.r.t. the highest order term, $u_{ttt}$ it is linear?

Comment: Yes, it is linear in the highest order derivates $u_{ttt}$; so it  is a quasilinear equation.